# How can I achieve separate colors for current, local, and remote ref names when using a custom git log format?

Tags: git, colors

I have a custom git log format that I use. I have `color.ui=true` set in my `.gitconfig`. For example this simple format:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %d %s" --decorate
```

This would print something like

```
52a41e0 (HEAD, local) Commit message foo
185bd17 (remote) The commit message
```

HEAD, local, remote will be output without color compared to `git log --oneline --decorate` which will outupt HEAD (in 'bold cyan'), local (in 'bold green') and remote (in 'bold red') with color. Now I can wrap the `%d` with something like `%Cred%d%Creset` which will cause **all** ref names to be red.

How can I get current, local, and remote ref names to have seperate colors when using a custom format with git log?

Comment: I don't think it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log/5892582#5892582

Comment: Ack, didn't look on stack overflow. That's too bad though.

Comment: @VonC Maybe you should add that as an answer?

Comment: @N.N. I have. On Stack Overflow. About one of the 10 *thousands* questions on Git.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can now use `%C(auto)` as of git 1.8.3, [according to this Atlassian blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/highlights-git-1-8-3/);

```
git log --format=format:'%h%C(auto)%d%C(reset) %s (%an, %ar)'
```

gives

[image]

— Again, courtesy of [VonC on "Color in git-log"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log/5892582#5892582), reposted here for the convenience of inbound googlers.

Answer (score 5):

> The `git log --decorate` will put by default:
>
> - the HEAD in cyan
> - the remote branches in red
> - the tag in green
>
> and can be changed through  **`color.decorate`** config.
>
> But the [`git log --format`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats) don't offer a way to display specifically the `HEAD` *or* remotes *or* branch: all three are displayed through `%d`, with one color possible.

— [VonC on "Color in git-log"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log/5892582#5892582)